# How to send customized reposne using Twilio API?

Tags: python, twilio

I am new to Twilio API and I am calling to a number and I want to play a customized message. Can anyone tell me how to do it? I know that I have to create a response file but I am not sure how to give that file in URL.

Here is my code.

```
# Download the library from twilio.com/docs/libraries
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient  
# Get these credentials from http://twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "xxxxxx"
auth_token = "yyyyyy"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
# Make the call
call = client.calls.create(to="aaaaa", # Any phone number
from_="bbbbb", # Must be a valid Twilio number
url="??????")
print call.sid
```

What should I write in URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are a couple of things you can do here. The url you enter in the outgoing call needs to respond with some XML (TwiML) when Twilio requests it.

If you want Twilio to play a message, you could write the following TwiML:

```
<Response>
  <Say>Hello from my new Twilio app</Say>
</Response>
```

This can be a static file hosted anywhere. For example, you could use http://twimlbin.com/ to host it and then use the url given to you by that service.

Alternatively, you could create a webserver application using something like Python's Flask. There is a guide to this on the Twilio site here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/twiml/say-response. You can then open your local development site to Twilio using a tool like ngrok and there's a good explanation of how to do that in this blog post: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/10/test-your-webhooks-locally-with-ngrok.html.

Hope that helps, let me know if there's anything more I can help you with.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for helping me with this. It was very helpful to me. I want to know that do you know how to initiate a call at a particular time using Twilio API in Python. I know that there is one parameter named StartTime but I don't know where to pass it. It would be great if you can help me.

Comment: Are you looking to place a call at a particular time in the future?

Comment: Yes I want to call at a specific time in future.

Comment: You should look into cron, or other scheduling software, to schedule scripts to be run when you want them to be run. StartTime is a parameter that is set by Twilio based on the call you are making, you can't adjust it your self.